# switch off caps lock programmatically macos

Tags: swift, macos

I am trying to remap the caps lock key to the return key so far I did what I want, but the problem is the caps lock is switching on, so every key I press after I press caps lock will be capital. is it possible to switch caps lock key off programmatically? or even better, can I prevent it from switching on in the first place?

I tried to copy the event and send it again to turn it off, but the program entered a loop of calling myCGEventCallback again.

```
let eventMask = (1 << CGEventType.keyDown.rawValue) | (1 << CGEventType.keyUp.rawValue) | (1 << (CGEventType.flagsChanged.rawValue))
let eventTap = CGEvent.tapCreate(tap: CGEventTapLocation.cghidEventTap,
    place: CGEventTapPlacement.headInsertEventTap,
    options: CGEventTapOptions.defaultTap,
    eventsOfInterest: CGEventMask(eventMask),
    callback: myCGEventCallback,
    userInfo: nil);do {
        print("failed to create eventTap")
    };

func myCGEventCallback(proxy : CGEventTapProxy, type : CGEventType, event : 
CGEvent, refcon : UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) -> Unmanaged<CGEvent>? 
{
    var keyCode = event.getIntegerValueField(.keyboardEventKeycode);
    if keyCode == 0x39 //caps lock
    {
        event.setIntegerValueField(.keyboardEventKeycode, value: 0x24)  // return       
    }
    return Unmanaged.passRetained(event)
}
```

Comment: Do you want to switch off the caps lock key on the keyboard or do you want to convert to lower case characters if the caps lock is on?

Comment: Switching the caps look off would be perfect. Thank you so much

Comment: See [Simulate/Toggle CAPS LOCK programatically in OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30035131/simulate-toggle-caps-lock-programatically-in-os-x). Or switch the caps lock off in system prefs.

Comment: I will try that, but switch it off from the system preference the event won't fire anymore, and I won't be able to remap it anymore.

Comment: It worked thank you so much.